# Multi Language Application - with Community Support?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, multilingual

I have to create an application whose interface will be changed by end user for his lang.
and the end user may be the community which will change the all the UI details....

what will be the best way to do this?

if I go with .net resources then user needs to use the settelite assemblies and that they cant make them selves.

if I go for XML then also some of the end users don't know the XML also I guess CSV may be usefull.

can any one has better idea then CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Why do they need to have the satellite assemblies?  Why not give them the Resource files and then you would integrate them back into your build?

Comment: application will be used by n- number of languages not possible to buil and give everytime they need something like on the go !

Comment: @shahjapan: Why not?  Resource assemblies simply have to be dropped into the appropriate folder for the application.  You only have to add one new assembly for each new language you support.

Comment: yes, but end users wants to do it by them selves, and they can't generate assembly, everytime I have to generate the assembly and tell them to put in the installed folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking for a .net implementation of gettext